# django filter get parent to child

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-filter

i am using django(3.1.5). and i am trying to get parent model to child model by filter query
i have model like -

```
class Product(models.Model):
   product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
   is_feature = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class ProductGalleryImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_gallery_image = models.FileField(upload_to='path')
    is_feature = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

i am getting data from `SELECT * FROM products_product AS pp INNER JOIN products_productgalleryimage AS ppgi ON ppgi.product_id = pp.id WHERE ppgi.is_feature=1 AND pp.is_feature=1 AND is_approved=1 ORDER BY pp.created_at LIMIT 4` mysql query.

so how can i get data like this query in django filter query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you can add `related_name` to ProductGalleryImage for better query support like this

```py
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_images')
```

Then your query should be like this

```py
products=Product.objects.filter(is_approved=True, is_feature=True, product_images__is_feature=True).order_by('created_at')[:4]
```

Comment: not getting product_images model data in products

Comment: You added related_name??

Comment: yes i have add related_name 'product_images' in ProductGalleryImage model`s product

Comment: while doing  `for i in products:
                          print(i.product_gallery_image)`    i am getting error  `AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'product_gallery_image'`

Comment: maybe you forgot to do your migrations after adding `related_name`

Comment: After making migration and migrating you should get related manager

Comment: Then you will get images i.product_images.all()

Comment: yes now i get from  i.product_images.all() , thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop over the other related model like so:

```py
for product_gallery_image in product_instance.productgalleryimage_set.all():
    print(product_gallery_image.product_gallery_image)
```

The `productgalleryimage_set` here is simply the related model name in lowercase with _set appended. You can change this by setting the `related_name` attribute on the foreign key.
Note: This will perform a query to fetch each of the product_gallery_image objects of some product instance.

If you want to get the first object only:

```py
product_gallery_image = product_instance.productgalleryimage_set.first()
```

If you want to perform a join as in your example which will perform only one query you can use [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) (this will only work in forward direction for reverse direction look at [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)):

```py
product_gallery_images = ProductGalleryImage.objects.all().select_related('product')
for product_gallery_image in product_gallery_images:
    print(product_gallery_image.product.product_name)
    print(product_gallery_image.product_gallery_image)
```